# How to return an empty image using AWS API Gateway alone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to return content-type image from AWS API Gateway without the use of a lambda. e.g. so I can reference in  on a page.

The returning type needs to be an image content type with no image.

I see that AWS have now implemented binary support but I have been unable to do the above.

Comment: What have you tried, and in what sense is it not working?  Also, it doesn't really make sense to return an "image" content type with no image since that's an error.  Are you wanting something like a 1 x 1 clear pixel tracking gif?

Comment: Yes, its for a tracking pixel but I do not want an image - there's no need to return the actual image, even a 1x1 pixel. So basically return HTTP 204 No Content.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work this one out.

You might be able to do have less steps but this is what I ended up with.

1. Create a model for content-type image/png with a body of {} (I called it emptyimage)
2. Create a GET method.
3. Integration request: This is just a MOCK; no need to change anything else.
4. Integration response

   - Remove the 200
   - Add 2\d{2} regex with a method response status of 204
   - Add response header of content-type
5. Method response.

   - Remove 200
   - Add 204
   - Response headers content-type
   - content-type response set to emptyimage model (created previously)

Calling the API returns a valid 204 no content response for content-type image/png.

If you render this pixel by using javascript you avoid an img tag being required in the dom and you dont get a browser missing image placeholder.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> (new Image()).src = "{url}"; </script>
```

Comment: And the browser doesn't treat this as a ⌧ broken image?

Comment: Well, its a valid response with no content and if you use javascript to load the image it doesnt inject/need an image tag in the dom and show a missing image; e.g. <script type="text/javascript">
(new Image()).src = "{url}";
</script>. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is the best/only way to do it with a MOCK integration.